# What are the risks to turn off firewalld on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, firewall, linux-mint

I have my macbook pro monopolized by Linux Mint 19.

How ever there is a issue keeps bothering me, the firewalld can not be stopped everytime I try to shutdown or restart the OS. To solve this, I guess I could disable the firewall one thing for all.

My question is, what are the risks to disable the firewalld on Linux Mint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the firewall removes a layer if protection by allowing ports/services to be more widely accessible then intended. If there are no software bugs or configuration issues it should make no difference - in practice systems and people are not perfect.

If you think of security as made up of layers, you are removing 1 layer.

If you are on a home network with limited devices that you trust, and are behind a NAT gateway, you are fairly protected by that as well (but if a device on thr LAN is compromised there is one less layer of protection)